# Where does the background story in A Song of Ice and Fire come from?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

As I can read, the author of the series created several books in the series starting with the book *A Game of Thrones*. I'm watching the series on TV (I haven't read the books).

When I watched something in the show that I do not fully understand or want to brush up on, I go search the web and usually find the information in Wikipedia. Often I also find a full timeline from before the first book, and I wonder **where does this information come from?** Whoever wrote this must have this information from somewhere - I just don't seem to understand where, since the first book starts around the same time the first episode of the first series in the TV show?

Comment: I'm cool with people down voting, it would just be nice if someone would write what is wrong? Is it a duplicate, then link to the duplicate post, is it badly worded, then edit the post. Is it obvious? It wasn't for me. Please elaborate people (had several both upvotes and downvotes)

Comment: Wikipedia (and other Wikis) generally have sources for information listed on the page somewhere, that's always a good place to start.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's a lot more history (both ancient and recent) discussed in the books than on the TV series, since if you're adapting close to 10,000 pages of novels (including the as-yet unpublished ones) to maybe 70 hours of TV you obviously have to leave a lot out. While the action starts in the same place, the characters spend a lot longer talking about the history that has got them to this point. There's also a series of novellas by George R R Martin (the ["Dunk and Egg"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Dunk_and_Egg) stories) that's set in Westeros around 90 years before the beginning of *A Game of Thrones* and fills in a lot of historical background from that period.

Comment: There's also tons of info that GRRM has revealed outside of the books (from readings, conventions, the Amoka portraits ... etc).

Comment: And now the World of Ice and Fire as well.

Answer (score 9):

All info about the world of *A song of ice and fire* comes from the author in one way or another. Most likely some people have collected all references to the history from the books and used those for the wiki. [This is the book](http://www.georgerrmartin.com/grrm_book/worldoficeandfire/) that is planned that contains just that.

Answer (score 5):

The information comes from the books themselves. There are tons of (in-world)historical mentions on the books that are not mentioned on the TV series.

There are also 4 prequel books (Dunk and Egg) that take place some years before A Song of Ice and Fire and give more historical insight to the series.

I would recommend reading all the books (the A Song of Ice and Fire series at the least) if you want to fully understand what is going on.

Comment: Four prequels now. *The Princess and the Queen* has been out for a while now.

Comment: @SystemDown, Sorry, didn't know it was out!

Comment: No worries. You can find it in the anthology "Dangerous Women". It's not a Dunk and Egg story though.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of important backstory comes from the first book. AGoT tells us why Robert Baratheon is so adamant about trying to kill Daenerys and Viserys and thus wipe out the Targaryen name completely.

On top of that, the story of Robert's Rebellion (which predates AGoT by about 14 years, as I believe Catelyn mentions that Ned was at war when Robb Stark was born) is detailed greatly, as it tells how the story of the Mad King Aerys Targaryen, how the Baratheons became the rulers of Westeros, and how the Targaryens are all but extinct. Robert's Rebellion ties many of the major characters together and helps define them, as Jaime and Tywin Lannister, Robb Stark, Gregor Clegane, and Robert and Stannis Baratheon (Renly was only a few years old at this point) all had important roles in this story.

**As with any adaptation, there are changes that have to be made, and details that have to be left out.** Unfortunately, that meant that most of the series' "prologue" (for lack of a better term) in the form of Robert's Rebellion and other stories that predate the events of the show were left out. There are pictures from unaired footage (most likely from the original pilot) that show the deaths of Ned Stark's father and brother at the hand of Mad King Aerys. It is likely the original pilot would have gone into some depth on this, but **where film is the art of showing, not telling,** giving long flashbacks like the book does (thus taking us out of the main story) would detract from the story and confuse watchers. Keeping this in mind, the show's writers put in the most important details, and that is enough to keep the show-only folks on track.

**In short:** The books have a TON of content pertaining to backstory, especially the first book. However, in order to keep a season's adaptation in 10 hours, a lot of material will still be cut. Unfortunately, a lot of the cut material was backstory. If you're interested in backstory, check out the books. They're definitely worth a read.

Answer (score 3):

All that background story comes from the Books series.

There are currently 5 books in the series:

1. *A Game of Thrones (1996)*
2. *A Clash of Kings (1998)*
3. *A Storm of Swords (2000)*
4. *A Feast for Crows (2005)*
5. *A Dance with Dragons (2011)*

The sixth book, *The Winds of Winter*, is still in writing.

George has [indicated](http://www.webcitation.org/66ff8sIb7?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ew.com%2Few%2Farticle%2F0%2C%2C20470532_20511966%2C00.html) that he wishes to end the series with the seventh book *A Dream of Spring* however he also maintained that might change.

George R.R. Martin has also written several prequels for the series which are:

1. *Tales of Dunk and Egg (Total 6-12 planned installments with 9 named and 3 released - Focused on Adventures of Ser Duncan the Tall who lived from reigns of King Daeron II's to King Aegon V's):*

   1. *Dunk & Egg: The Hedge Knight (1998)*
   2. *Dunk & Egg: The Sworn Sword (2003)*
   3. *Dunk & Egg: The Mystery Knight (2010)*
   4. *Dunk & Egg: The She-Wolves of Winterfell (Under progress)*
   5. *Dunk & Egg: The Village Hero (Under progress)*
   6. *Dunk & Egg: The Sellsword (Planned)*
   7. *Dunk & Egg: The Champion (Planned)*
   8. *Dunk & Egg: The Kingsguard (Planned)*
   9. *Dunk & Egg: The Lord Commander (Planned)*
2. *The Princess and The Queen<sup>**1**</sup> (2013)*
3. *The Rogue Prince<sup>**2**</sup> (2014)*
4. *The Sons of the Dragon<sup>**3**</sup> (2017)*

George has also written a companion book titled *The Lands of Ice and Fire (2012)* in which the maps are drawn by Jonathan Roberts.

Other than that, George has also written another  companion book titled [*The World of Ice and Fire (2014)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_of_Ice_%26_Fire) in partnership with Elio M. García Jr. and Linda Antonsson which is basically all about the history, cultures, religions and geography of Planetos.

A planned complete history of House Targaryen officially titled *Blood of the Dragon*, and unofficially called the *GRRMarillion* is also in the works.

---

<sub>**1.** Published in *The Dangerous Women* anthology. It covers the Targaryen Civil War dubbed "Dance of the Dragons".</sub>

<sub>**2.** Published in *The Rogues* anthology. It revolves around the Life of Prince Daemon Targaryen and his role in the Dance.</sub>

<sub>**3.** Published in *The Book of Swords* anthology. It is focused on the reigns of Kings Aenys and Maegor the Cruel.</sub>